# Force SSL on checkout page while everything else uses standard HTTP

Tags: ssl, .htaccess, https

I am trying to use .htaccess to make one page on my site redirect to it's https counterpart. The checkout.php page lives in the root / html folder of the site. ( /checkout.php ). I tried using this : (which i found online somewhere). I put it up and got an internal server error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The idea is, if a customer is on the checkout.php page then redirect to https... if they aren't, redirect to http. Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Rewrite code I use to redirect plain http wordpress admin page access to https. You can customize it to your needs.

```
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
     RewriteRule ^wp-admin https://www.example.com/wp-admin [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am still having a bit of trouble :
the line 
RewriteRule ^wp-admin https://www.example.com/wp-admin [R=301,L]

for my implementation would I just change ^wp-admin to ^checkout.php and also the change to the url to the right? I did that and it gave me an internal server error.